How to disable IP settings randomization of wifi sharing?
I can not see a way to set up the network parameters if I start a wifi sharing in AP mode. The usual behavior of my phones is that they randomly allocate a /24 block somewhere below 192.168.0.0/16, and everything will be random there. They are also re-generated, if the wifi stops working on any reason.
I want to change it. I want the good old times back as I just could determine the IP range, the IP of the AP in it and that worked well. It would be yet much better if I could even create a mac-ip mapping, like it is possible in any dhcp daemon on the Linuxes; but I think it will remain a dream today.
Can I do it? I have here a rooted Android 11.

Note, it is not about the MAC randomizations. If you are now trying to formulate an answer about the "use device MAC" setting in the network connections menu, that will be an answer for a different question.
